# save and load NSMutableArray Fails

Tags: iphone, nsmutablearray, nsuserdefaults

i am kind of new to saving `NSMutableArray` To `NSUerdefaults`.

here is the declaration of the iVar:
.h file

```
@interface GameData : NSObject {

NSMutableArray *PPLayers;
```

}

```
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSMutableArray *PPLayers;
```

.m file

@synthesize PPLayers;

here is how i am adding a object to the array and saving it to the default:

```
-(void)AddObject:(NSString *) object ToArray:(NSMutableArray*)array{
if (array == PShoes) {
    [PShoes addObject:object];
    NSLog(@"Object : %@",object);
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setValue:PPLayers forKey:@"pplayers"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];
    NSLog(@"%@",PPLayers);
}
```

sometimes it works and sometime the app crashes.

and here is how i am trying to load the array:

```
    PPLayers = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]mutableArrayValueForKey:@"pplayers"];
```

something is wrong here but i dont know what.
sometimes when i load it it gives me `null`.
the app save it only when i run it from the simulator.
i would like to get some help plz.
thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
         [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setValue:PPLayers forKey:@"pplayers"];

         NSArray *NewPPLayers =[[NSArray alloc]initwithArray:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]mutableArrayValueForKey:@"pplayers"]];
```